# ¿Cómo saber si quien está accediendo a la URL actual es un bot o un rastreador (crawler)?

Tags: php, google-analytics

En un dominio he creado mi propio programa para mostrar estadísticas sencillas tomadas de Google Analytics. Básicamente muestro solamente la cantidad de visitas de las páginas basadas en los datos de Google Analytics en dos sitios:

- **A.** En el footer de la página principal tengo un widget que me muestra las páginas más visitadas en la presente semana. Para no consultar a GA cada vez que se entra en esa página, leo los datos desde un archivo JSON el cual es actualizado cada dos horas a través de un cron que hace la petición a GA.
- **B.** En cada página muestro el total de visitas de la misma consultando datos de GA. Esto se hace cada vez que la página es visitada. Aquí no hay ningún control. Creo que aquí está el problema y que se debe a los crawlers o a los bots que rastrean el sitio.

En **B.** no establecí ningún control porque el sitio no es enormemente visitado. Yo estimo una media de 3.000 visitas por día. En la consola de Google yo tengo una cuota de 50,000 peticiones diarias a la API y 100 consultas por 100 segundos por usuario.

Como decía, el tráfico que se genera en mi sitio no supera esa capacidad (a no ser que me haya hecho famoso de hoy para mañana, lo cual dudo mucho :) ).

El hecho es que la cuota se está excediendo desde hace dos o tres días, mi `error_log` está lleno de mensajes como este:

> ```
> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message 
> '{
>   "error": {
>       "errors": [{
>           "domain": "global",
>           "reason": "userRateLimitExceeded",
>           "message": "Quota Error: User Rate Limit Exceeded."
>       }],
>       "code": 403,
>       "message": "Quota Error: User Rate Limit Exceeded."
>   }
> }' in /vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php:118
> ```

La única explicación lógica que encuentro es que mi sitio esté siendo rastreado por varios bots o crawlers para indexarlo o lo que sea, los cuales rompen básicamente con el límite de consultas por 100 segundos. En el día de hoy yo tengo un total de `16,204` consultas a la API (por lo que no es el límite diario el que está siendo excedido). Ni tampoco creo que `16,204` personales *normales*  hayan visitado mi sitio hoy... Eso llegará, cuando sea famoso :)

Como dato adicional, **no uso esa clave de API ni ese proyecto para nada más**, eso descarta la posibilidad de que se esté consultando la API de GA desde otro sitio o aplicación.

Mi pregunta es **¿cómo determinar en el código PHP que quien está accediendo a la URL actual no es un bot o un crawler, sino un usuario normal?**.

Trato de determinar eso para no enviar la petición a GA en ese caso. Creo que así evitaré que se exceda el límite de cuota.

Comment: Lo había puesto como respuesta, pero mejor casi como comentario porque no responde directamente a la pregunta de los bots: el mensaje de error que recibes no ocurre por llegar al límite diario de peticiones sino por hacer demasiadas llamadas concurrentes. Lo puedes ver en [tabla de errores de la documentación de la API de Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/errors#error_table), donde se describe el problema y se da un algoritmo para solucionar (o más bien rodear) el problema.

Comment: Gracias @AlvaroMontoro, soy consciente de que no se trata de un exceso en el límite diario (lo digo en la pregunta), sino de un exceso en el límite de consultas por 100 segundos. Yo no creo que el sitio tenga a ninguna hora 100 usuarios por segundo, por eso orienté el problema hacia posibles rastreadores o algo así.

Answer (score 2):

La solución estándar es el `User-Agent`, que es una cabecera HTTP que (puede) enviar el cliente (navegador) indicando qué software es. Normalmente la idea es que si el cliente es un navegador el usuario es un humano (o un gato paseando por el teclado).

No están muy estandarizadas (es simplemente un String que cada vendedor proporciona) pero tampoco hay tantos navegadores en el mercado. Por ejemplo para Firefox 47:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0

Seguro que habrá otras páginas con listas de los User-Agents de los navegadores, [yo he encontrado ésta de Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent).

Para obtener el valor en PHP:

```
$useragent = $_SERVER ['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
```

Comment: ¿Entonces según tú tendría que tener una lista de los `User Agent` para comparar si `$useragent` se encuentra en esa lista? En ese caso supongo que tendría que tener una lista con cada versión e ir actualizando dicha lista... ¿PHP no tendrá ninguna función que haga eso y que mantenga una lista de `User Agent` actualizada?

Comment: La base de todo es esa cabecera. En PHP hay una función [getBrowser](http://php.net/manual/es/function.get-browser.php) pero no parece darte lo que buscas; pero en los comentarios apuntan a este package (no lo he usado): https://github.com/ThaDafinser/UserAgentParser